# Oracle Tree structure

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to create a tree structure without using connect by and using oracle analytic functions like dense_rank for example?
I am trying to recreate this query from Oracle HR schema.

```
SELECT last_name, employee_id, manager_id, LEVEL
      FROM employees
      START WITH employee_id = 100
      CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id
      ORDER SIBLINGS BY last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query with a `SEARCH` clause to mimic the hierarchical query with `ORDER SIBLINGS BY`:

```sql
WITH emps (last_name, employee_id, manager_id, depth) AS (
  SELECT last_name, employee_id, manager_id, 1
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  employee_id = 100
UNION ALL
  SELECT e.last_name, e.employee_id, e.manager_id, p.depth + 1
  FROM   employees e
         INNER JOIN emps p
         ON p.employee_id = e.manager_id
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY last_name SET order_id
SELECT last_name, employee_id, manager_id, depth
FROM   emps;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (last_name, employee_id, manager_id) AS
SELECT 'Alice', 100, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', 101, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', 102, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Debra', 103, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Emily', 104, 101 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fiona', 105, 104 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gerri', 106, 102 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Holly', 107, 102 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Irene', 108, 107 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Julia', 109, 106 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Kerry', 110, 104 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| LAST_NAME | EMPLOYEE_ID | MANAGER_ID | DEPTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 100 | *null* | 1 |
| Beryl | 101 | 100 | 2 |
| Emily | 104 | 101 | 3 |
| Fiona | 105 | 104 | 4 |
| Kerry | 110 | 104 | 4 |
| Carol | 102 | 100 | 2 |
| Gerri | 106 | 102 | 3 |
| Julia | 109 | 106 | 4 |
| Holly | 107 | 102 | 3 |
| Irene | 108 | 107 | 4 |
| Debra | 103 | 100 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DAE0QsYd)